# PCL filter, "the input dataset is not from a projective device"

Tags: point-cloud-library, ros, openni

I use Kinect to build a 3D cloud, when I tried to use PCL's StatisticalOutlierRemoval or RadiusOutlierRemoval, it says that "the input dataset is not from a projective device", however my clouds seems quite projective.
Here is my code for building the cloud:

```
for (int i = 0; i < colNumber; i++)
    {
        if (data_d[i] != 0)
        {
            Zw = data_d[i] * (3.5-1.2) / 255 + 1.2;//kinect's range 1.2~3.5m
            Xw = (i - u0) * Zw / fx;
            Yw = (j - v0) * Zw / fy;
            cloud_a.points[cloud_index].x = Xw;
            cloud_a.points[cloud_index].y = Yw;
            cloud_a.points[cloud_index].z = Zw;
            cloud_a.points[cloud_index].r = data_c[3 * i + 2];
            cloud_a.points[cloud_index].g = data_c[3 * i + 1];
            cloud_a.points[cloud_index].b = data_c[3 * i];
            cloud_index++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "error point in cloud building" << endl;
        }
    }
```

and my cloud seems like:
[cloud view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv8Xr.jpg)
I have been working on it for hours, still don't know how to solve it.
Here is the description for projective:

> An projectable point cloud dataset is the name given to point clouds that have a correlation according to a pinhole camera model between the (u,v) index of a point in the organized point cloud and the actual 3D values. This correlation can be expressed in it’s easiest form as: u = f*x/z and v = f*y/z

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason myself, I made a mistake about the width and the height. It should be as the same as the image you get found the Kinect device.